# Dropbox disable_access_token API not working for logging out user

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I am working on chrome extension where I need to authenticate the user on Dropbox and the user needs to approve the app for use with Dropbox. For this I am using the `OAuth2.0` authentication as mentioned in the Dropbox API. The code for the same is [here](http://codeshare.io/jPB67). Now when the user clicks on the logout button, a request is sent to `/disable_access_token` endpoint on Dropbox, but on clicking the login button again the user gets logged in again without any credentials needed to do so. I am not even setting any cookies in my extension.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has already authorized the app, and is already logged in to the Dropbox site itself (that is, dropbox.com, not your site) they may get automatically redirected through the app authorization flow.

You can control this behavior via the `force_reapprove` parameter:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-authorize